# How to access child's instance variable in super / parent class

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, instance-variables

I have the following example:

```
class A
   @Values = {}

   def initialize()
     @Values.each{ |_key, _val|
        puts("Key: #{_key}, Val: #{_val}")
     }
   end
end

class B < A
  @Values = { "Test1": "1", "Test2": "2"}

  def initialize()
    super()
  end
end
```

My Problem:

```
B.new()
```

Creates no output - so @Values from class B are not available in class A. Why? How can I access them?

========= Update =========
Thank you for your answers!

@Mosab Muhammad: Yeah - i'm really not sure when to use {} and when to use do end ... i will have a look at both when to use.

> {} (usually used for single-line blocks) or do..end (used for
>   multi-line blocks).

Thats right - i read it's kind of a rail convention to do so, but theres more - {} and do end behave different.

@@ would be an option, but i don't think its a good idea to edit class variables - as you mentioned, it can have realy nasty side effects.

@Aleksei Matiushkin - Thank you! I will take a look into self.class.instance_variable_get and will see, how it behaves and if it will solve my problem!

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Hi. If some answers where helpful, the posters would appreciate an upvote. An acceptance of the best answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question `@Values from class B are not available in class A. Why?` is:
The instance variable declared on class level can not be accessed on object level.

And The answer to your question `How can i access them?` is: You can declare a class variable `@@values` instead of instance variable `@values` in `initialize` method.

Your example will be changed to:

```
class A
  @@values = {}

  def initialize()
    @@values.each{ |_key, _val|
      puts("Key: #{_key}, Val: #{_val}")
    }
  end
end

class B < A
  @@values = { "Test1": "1", "Test2": "2"}
end
```

Now `B.new` Will output

```
Key: Test1, Val: 1
Key: Test2, Val: 2
```

Another Answer:

```
class A

   def initialize()
     @values ||= {}
     @values.each{ |_key, _val|
        puts("Key: #{_key}, Val: #{_val}")
     }
   end
end

class B < A

  def initialize()
    @values = { "Test1": "1", "Test2": "2"}
    super()
  end
end
```

Note: Class variables are shared between related classes and can be overwritten from a child class. This mean if you override the class variable `@@values` in B Class, the `@@values` in A class will be overwritten.

Another Note: {} (usually used for single-line blocks) or do..end (used for multi-line blocks).

For Example:
Use

```
def initialize()
  @Values.each{ |_key, _val| puts("Key: #{_key}, Val: #{_val}") }
end
```

Instead of:

```
def initialize()
  @Values.each{ |_key, _val|
    puts("Key: #{_key}, Val: #{_val}")
  }
end
```

OR

Use

```
def initialize()
  @Values.each do |_key, _val|
    puts("Key: #{_key}, Val: #{_val}")
  end
end
```

Instead of:

```
def initialize()
  @Values.each{ |_key, _val|
    puts("Key: #{_key}, Val: #{_val}")
  }
end
```

Comment: This was not the question. It is about __instance__ variables, not class variables.

Comment: I told you that The instance variable (in your case @values) declared on class level can not be accessed on object level(i.e: in initialize method)

Comment: Well, still does not answer the question, though.

Comment: Gotcha, I updated my answer to include the answer you want. Please note that instance variables should be declared inside a method not in class scope.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this code has very many issues, so I’d answer the exact question stated. If you want the variable to be accessible from both class and instant context, use the *class variable* instead:

```
class A
  @@values = {}
  def initialize
    @@values.each{ |key, val|
      puts("Key: #{key}, Val: #{val}")
    }
  end
end

class B < A
  @@values = { "Test1" => "1", "Test2" => "2"}
  def initialize
    super
  end
end

B.new
#⇒ Key: Test1, Val: 1
#  Key: Test2, Val: 2
```

Comment: This was not the question. It is about __instance__ variables, not class variables.

Comment: @mbuechmann let me decide myself how and what to answer. BTW, your answer violates SRP (your parent class implementation _depends_ on children, which is silly.)

Comment: Of course you are welcome to answer as you like. My comment is still valid and I should be allowed to point things out.